Why I cannot use command in an `expl3`-based spread align box?
Similar to command \makebox[<dim>][s]{<content>}, I create this wheel via expl3:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__skyrmion_cover_spread_box:nn #1#2
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \hbox_to_wd:nn {#1}
      { \tl_map_inline:Nn {#2} { ##1 \hfil } \unskip }
  }

Then, I want to read a "matrix" now, the matrix is stored in a token list
\tl_set:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {Element~11+Element~12/Element~21+Element~22}

it's row is separated by sign /, and it's col is separated by sign +. The function used to read the matrix like this is defined like:
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq {/} {#1}
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq {+}
      { \exp_args:NNe \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq {#2} }
    \exp_args:NNe \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq {#3}
    \seq_clear:N \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq
    \seq_clear:N \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq
  }

Then, I'd like to spread align the string "Element~22" that in the 2nd row, 2nd column of the matrix:
\__skyrmion_spread_box:nn {10em}
  { \__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2} }

Now, many errors blood out:
Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \???
Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \???
...

I've tried adding interfaces like \exp_args:, but this doesn't work. What's more, \makebox can solve this problem, but it will return me warning (maybe \msg_info_text info?) like
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)

I cannot bear this, even there maybe a method can prevent this by change some value in Knuth's TeX algorithm.
The following is my MWE:
\documentclass{ctexart}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__skyrmion_spread_box:nn #1#2
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \hbox_to_wd:nn {#1}
      { \tl_map_inline:Nn {#2} { ##1 \hfil } \unskip }
  }

\tl_set:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {Element~11+Element~12/Element~21+Element~22}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq {/} {#1}
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq {+}
      { \exp_args:NNe \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq {#2} }
    \exp_args:NNe \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq {#3}
    \seq_clear:N \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq
    \seq_clear:N \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq
  }

\begin{document}

The~elements~are~the~following:\par

A11 = 
\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {1}{1};~
A12 = 
\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {1}{2};\par
A21 = 
\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{1};~
A22 = 
\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2}\par

Now,~ I'd~like~to~spread~the~string~"Element~22"

\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2}\par

% \__skyrmion_spread_box:nn {10em}
%   { \__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2} }

\makebox[10em][s]{\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2}}

\end{document}


Can you please be more specific about the expected output? Your code is surely wrong in several places, but fixing it requires to know what you really want to achieve.

I'll add the l3 version I think you were looking for

The MWE produces an underful box warning as it can be simplified to
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makebox[10em][s]{Element 2}

\end{document}


The box is forced to be 10em wide but there is not enough stretchy specae available to stretch the text to that width so the box is underfull.
You need to add more stretch space by explicitly adding space, or increasing the stretch component of inter-word space, or by changing [s] to [l] so the text is not streteched at all.
If you uncomment the L3 version you get
! Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \???  
                 ! LaTeX Error: A sequence was misused.

as you have
\tl_map_inline:Nn {#2}
:N functions always expect a single unbraced token and you have passed it the brace group {\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2}}
Here I don't think you want a map at all, you just want to set a single element on a single box, just as in the \makebox example.  You had \hfil which would avoid the underfill hbox and left align (like \makebox[l] but I took it out to stretch the content, like \makebox[c])
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__skyrmion_spread_box:nn #1#2
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \hbox_to_wd:nn {#1}
      { #2  }
  }

\tl_set:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {Element~11+Element~12/Element~21+Element~22}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq {/} {#1}
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq {+}
      { \exp_args:NNe \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq {#2} }
    \exp_args:NNe \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq {#3}
    \seq_clear:N \l__skyrmion_tmprow_seq
    \seq_clear:N \l__skyrmion_tmpcol_seq
  }

\begin{document}

The~elements~are~the~following:\par

A11 = 
\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {1}{1};~
A12 = 
\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {1}{2};\par
A21 = 
\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{1};~
A22 = 
\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2}\par

Now,~ I'd~like~to~spread~the~string~"Element~22"

\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2}\par


{\hbadness=10000
 \__skyrmion_spread_box:nn {10em}
   { \__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2} }

   \par
   
\makebox[10em][s]{\__skyrmion_get_element:Nnn \l__skyrmion_tmp_tl {2}{2}}

}

\end{document}



For some reason, text must be stretched to a specific width, and it's better to be no warning. So, I have to create a command via expl3 for stretching text without warning.

@Skyrmion well as I wrote if there is always a word space you could make the inter word space more stretchy, but if any item has no space eg is just abc then it can't be stretched to 10em so all you could do is suppress the warning (set \hbadness=10000)

I have tried this method, and certainly the warning disappeared. But I am writing a class, doing this users will not aware that someplace the badness is too large. So, I think that it's better to solve the question's main part about expl3.

@Skyrmion But if Element 22 is just a letter c, what should happen?  How should that get stretched to fill the 10em box?

@Teepeemm The letter c will centered, but it's left and right will be filled with a stretched space (or glue?). Anyway, I just want to achieve the effect of \makebox[<dim>][s]{<text>} but without warnings.

@Skyrmion {\hbadness=10000 \makebox[<dim>][s]{<text>}}  suppresses warnings

@Skyrmion you say you want s (stretched) but your L3 code is using ##1 \hfil } so adding hfill glue on the right of each box so will never make an underfull box and is exactly like \makebox[l] not \makebox[s]
